# How do you use C++ fmt on CentOS9?

Tags: c++, linux, centos, c++20, fmt

I installed `fmt` using `dnf install fmt`. It was successful. But when I try to use it as `#include <fmt/format.h>` it says it is not found. I downloaded `include` from fmt git page so it finds `format.h` now with `-I...` but I have compilation errors.

```
undefined reference to `fmt::v8::vformat[abi:cxx11](fmt::v8::basic_string_view<char>, fmt::v8::basic_format_args<fmt::v8::basic_format_context<fmt::v8::appender, char> >)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I tried `-lfmt` but it errors with

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lfmt
```

I cant find any help for this type of use on the git.

How do you use `fmt` lib on CentOS9 **without building `fmt`** project manually?

EIDT: dnf install output
[image]

Comment: On CentOS or Fedora, no software should be installed manually, like that, but always via proper rpm packaging. There's a reason for that, and in general downloading random files off the Internet is unlikely to solve anything. For development, the usual name of the package is "something-devel". If you were to "dnf install fmt-devel" you would discover that this installs `fmt/core.h`, `fmt/format.h`, and all other header files, as well as the appropriate symlink that makes `-lfmt` work correctly.

Comment: ok let me try. however i dont understand your remark "always via proper rpm" - `dnf install` installed an rpm.. why is it not "proper" ? P.S. - I added screenshot from dnf install, it says `fmt-8.1.1-5.el9.x86_64.rpm`

Comment: I actually tried `fmt/format.h` and `fmt/core.h` - I edited the question

Comment: @SamVarshavchik - it worked. could you please write it as an answer? also - how do I deploy it then? i dont want on prod machine to have any devel stuff. do i need to install `fmt` ? or everything i need is already linked and is placed in the executable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fedora/RHEL/CentOS uses the following naming convention for all packages that installed shared libraries:

**name** - this package contains runtime shared libraries that are needed to run programs that are linked with this library.

**name**`-devel` - the "devel" packages contains header files and the symbolic links that allow you to link with the shared library when developing applications that use this library.

You need both packages to compile the code that uses the library. The `devel` package specifies a dependency on the main package, so `dnf install name-devel` is going to install both packages.

You should invest a little bit of time to learn how to build your own `rpm` packages. It's not that complicated. When you build your package `rpmbuild` will take care of analyzing the resulting binary, discovering which shared libraries it links with, then recording the appropriate dependency in your own `rpm` package, so installing it will pull in only the main `name` package.